# How to avoid 'headers already sent' within Promise chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on a 'change password' functionality. I am starting to learn more about Promises and have the following code:

```
router.post('/change-password', verifyToken, csrfProtection, (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body.password_current || !req.body.password_new) {
    req.flash('info', 'Please fill in both fields.');
    return res.redirect('/change-password');
  }
  const data = {};
  data.password = req.body.password_new;
  tokenHandler.verifyToken(req.cookies.token)
    .then((decoded) => {
      return User.findOne({ '_id.user_id': decoded.user });
    })
    .then((user) => {
      data.userId = ObjectId(user._id.user_id);
      return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password_current, user.password);
    })
    .then((allowed) => {
      if (!allowed) {
        return res.redirect('/change-password');
      }
      console.log('I am not here');
      return User.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id.user_id': data.userId }, { password: data.password }, { new: true });
    })
    .then(() => {
      return res.redirect('/change-password');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return next(err);
    });
});
```

I love how Promises are preventing the 'callback hell'. The problem is that I am receiving a 'headers already sent' error. I know that is because I can't escape the chain and that it saves up all the results (unless you throw an Error). To fix the problem I used the following:

```
router.post('/change-password', verifyToken, csrfProtection, (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body.password_current || !req.body.password_new) {
    req.flash('info', 'Please fill in both fields.');
    return res.redirect('/change-password');
  }
  const data = {};
  data.password = req.body.password_new;
  tokenHandler.verifyToken(req.cookies.token)
    .then((decoded) => {
      User.findOne({ '_id.user_id': decoded.user }).then((user) => {
        data.userId = ObjectId(user._id.user_id);
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password_current, user.password).then((allowed) => {
          if (!allowed) {
            return res.redirect('/change-password');
          }
          User.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id.user_id': data.userId }, { password: data.password }).then((doc) => {
            console.log(doc);
            return res.redirect('/change-password');
          });
        });
      });
    });
});
```

The question is: Is there a better solution to fix the 'header already sent' error. Because I have the feeling that my solution is actually a few steps away from a 'callback hell' structure.

Comment: You only need to nest the part of the `then` chain that is supposed to go in the `else` part of the condition, not everything. Also you shouldn't remove the `.catch()` in the end.

Comment: Do you really want to the same `res.redirect('/change-password');` even if they're not `allowed`? In that case, just don't call `res.redirect` twice, but put the `return User.findOneAndUpdate(…)` inside an `if (allowed)` and continue the chain to the redirect call normally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reminder that I forgot about the `.catch()` block. :-) I need the redirects to deliver a different 'flash' message. I could have found other solutions to prevent the 'header already sent' error.  But I was really curious how I could prevent it with this structure. Now I know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite it like this

```
router.post('/change-password', verifyToken, csrfProtection, (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body.password_current || !req.body.password_new) {
    req.flash('info', 'Please fill in both fields.');
    return res.redirect('/change-password');
  }
  const data = {};
  data.password = req.body.password_new;
  tokenHandler.verifyToken(req.cookies.token)
    .then((decoded) => {
      return User.findOne({ '_id.user_id': decoded.user });
    })
    .then((user) => {
      data.userId = ObjectId(user._id.user_id);
      return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password_current, user.password);
    })
    .then((allowed) => {
      if (!allowed) {
        return res.redirect('/change-password');
      }
     else{
        console.log('I am not here');
        return User.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id.user_id': data.userId }, { password: data.password }, { new: true })
          .then(() => {
                return res.redirect('/change-password');
             });
       }      
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return next(err);
    });
});
```

You can return a promise chain from within a `then` function.

Comment: Thank you! It makes so much more sense now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Node, you may also be able to re-write this using async / await. It generally makes things easier to reason about.

```
router.post('/change-password', verifyToken, csrfProtection, async (req, res, next) => {
if (!req.body.password_current || !req.body.password_new) {
    req.flash('info', 'Please fill in both fields.');
    return res.redirect('/change-password');
}

try {
    const data = {};
    data.password = req.body.password_new;
    const decoded = await tokenHandler.verifyToken(req.cookies.token);
    const user = await User.findOne({ '_id.user_id': decoded.user });
    data.userId = ObjectId(user._id.user_id);
    const allowed = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password_current, user.password);
    if (!allowed) {
        return res.redirect('/change-password');
    } else {
        await User.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id.user_id': data.userId }, { password: data.password }, { new: true });
    }
    return res.redirect('/change-password');
} catch (err) {
    return next(err);
}
});
```

You need Node.js >= 7 to use async/await.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried the async / await and it works! I only had to wrap the whole code within an IIFE. `(async () => { })();`